# Display Image in MVC4 View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, image, qr-code

Refering this [link,](http://www.jphellemons.nl/post/Generate-QR-Codes-with-AspNet-C.aspx) I created an QR code image using MessagingToolkit.QRCode.dll. 
How to display the saved image in the same view with the myLayout.
**Controller Code**

```
  [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult GenerateExcelQR(string Command, FormCollection collection)
    {
    if (Command == "Excel")
    {
    //  logic to generate Excel
    }
    else if(Command =="QRCode")
     // qr code logic //
        QRCodeEncoder encoder = new QRCodeEncoder();
        Bitmap img = encoder.Encode(qrcode);
        string path = Server.MapPath("/Images/QRCode.jpg"); 
        img.Save(path, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        return base.File(path,"image/jpeg"); // Displays the QR image without my layout.
     // return View(path,"image/jpeg");      // Returns an error specifying "Images\QRCode.jpg' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations."
    }
```

How to display the QRCode image in the Same View with the layout.
Any suggestions.
**EDIT**
ImageModel.cs

```
public static class ImageModel
    {
        public static string Image(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string path, string alt)
        {
            var img = new TagBuilder("img");
            img.MergeAttribute("src", path);
            img.MergeAttribute("alt", alt);
            return img.ToString(TagRenderMode.SelfClosing);
        }
    }
```

In view

```
@model IEnumerable<SampleECommerce.Models.CheckoutModel> // reference to 1st model to return values
@using SampleECommerce.Models; // for Imagemodel
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should return not a file, but a view, and in view render your image. Here Image - is a html helper:

```
public static HtmlString Image(this HtmlHelper helper, string path, string alt)
{
    var img = new TagBuilder("img");
    img.MergeAttribute("src", path);
    img.MergeAttribute("alt", alt);
    return new HtmlString(img.ToString(TagRenderMode.SelfClosing));
}
```

And then just use it in a view:

```
@Html.Image(path_to_your_image, "Description")
```

And in your controller use just `return View();`

To use this helper, you should create a folder in your project, for example 'Helpers'. Then, create file in this folder, for example 'HtmlImageHelper.cs', then put the content of helper in this file. After this, in your view at the top write: `using YourProjectName.Helpers`. After this you are able to use this html helper to render images

Comment: I tried return View(path,"image/jpeg"); to render the iamge in View. It throws error that the image is not found.

Comment: How to use this Htmlhelper code. I used this in my controller but it says the @Html.Imager misses assembly or reference.

Comment: yes. I tried. My view gets conflict with the model which is referred already and returns error.

Comment: @kk1076, edit your question, show error what you have and be more specific please

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27485/discussion-between-kk1076-and-alex-ovechkin)